# Unit Test that Snackbar

Tags: android, unit-testing

How do I unit test that a Snackbar shows and the action button launches starts an intent?

```
Snackbar.makeText(context, "message", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();"
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do this in a number of ways. Which one is best depends on your preferences, your architecture and the type you're using.

- One way is to use a test double, a spy, that keeps track of whether or not the show() method has been called. Then you assert against this, given some certain input.
- Another way is to assert against some kind of isVisible(). This method may or may not exist at the moment. If you control the type in question you might consider adding it (be careful with adding too many public methods just for querying the state of an object though).

EDIT: some example code of a spy test double:

```
public class FakeSnackbar extends Snackbar {

    public boolean Shown;

    @Override
    public void show() {
        Shown = true;
    }
}
```

I don't know specifically what an intent is in the context of android programming, but a similar method could possibly be used for that.